# SVG Arrow Down Arrow not rendering correctly

Tags: svg

I am writing a **right arrow** and **down arrow** using svg. The **right arrow** works fine with this code:

```html
<svg width="20px" height="40px">
      <defs>
        <marker
          id="right-arrow"
          markerWidth="4"
          markerHeight="8"
          refX="0"
          refY="1"
          viewBox="0 0 1 2"
        >
          <polygon points="0,0 1,1 0,2" fill="#3273dc" stroke="none" />
        </marker>
      </defs>
      <line
        x1="0"
        y1="50%"
        x2="100%"
        y2="50%"
        strokeWidth="2"
        markerEnd="url(#right-arrow)"
        stroke="#3273dc"
      />
    </svg>
```

[image: Right Arrow]

When I try to change this arrow to down arrow, the arrow tip is coming incorrectly using this code:

```html
<svg width="20px" height="20px">
      <defs>
        <marker
          id="down-arrow"
          markerWidth="4"
          markerHeight="8"
          refX="0"
          refY="1"
          viewBox="0 0 1 2"
          orient="auto-start-reverse"
        >
          <polygon points="0,0 2,2 2,0" fill="#3273dc" stroke="none" />
        </marker>
      </defs>
      <line
        x1="50%"
        y1="0"
        x2="50%"
        y2="100%"
        strokeWidth="2"
        markerEnd="url(#down-arrow)"
        stroke="#3273dc"
      />
    </svg>
```

[image: Down Arrow]

What is wrong with my down arrow code?

Comment: I see no arrows with either code, just lines

Comment: Firstly, `markerEnd=""` should be `marker-end=""`.  Secondly, you don't need two arrow definitions.  SVG will automatically rotate the arrowhead for you. The first one should work for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a different marker.You can use the `right-arrow`. The problem is that the marker is too small. In order to be able to see the marker I've changed the color to red. Also since your line goes from 0% to 100% the marker falls outside the svg canvas. I've change it to 90%.

Also you are using `markerEnd` I've changed it to `marker-end`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <defs>
       <marker
          id="right-arrow"
          markerWidth="2"
          markerHeight="4"
          refX="0"
          refY="1"
          orient="auto"
        >
          <polygon points="0,0 1,1 0,2" fill="red" stroke="none" />
        </marker>
        
      </defs>
      <line
        x1="0"
        y1="50%"
        x2="90%"
        y2="50%"
        strokeWidth="2"
        marker-end="url(#right-arrow)"
        stroke="#3273dc"
      />
    </svg>




<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
     
      <line
        x1="50%"
        y1="0"
        x2="50%"
        y2="90%"
        strokeWidth="2"
        marker-end="url(#right-arrow)"
        stroke="#3273dc"
        orient="auto-start-reverse"
      />
  

    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your down-arrow polygon points:

**Change**

```
points="0,0 2,2 2,0"
```

Above says within the viewBox:

1. move to x=0, y=0
2. then draw to x=2,y=2 (diagonally down)
3. then draw to x=2,y=0 (something odd)

**To**

```
points="0,0 0,2 1,2"
```

Above says within the viewBox:

1. move to x=0, y=0
2. then draw to x=0,y=2 (across)
3. then draw to x=1,y=2 (diagonally down to center point)

You can see this pattern in the [SVG specification on polygons](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/shapes.html#PolygonElement) that describes how polygons are drawn like a path. The SVG spec for path has a [down arrow example](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathElement)

Comment: Thanks for the links to the SVG spec.